# Load and Manipulate an SVG with JS that isn't part of the DOM

Tags: svg, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm using leaflet js with custom markers.  These markers need to move, change colors, and rotate.  Movement is fairly simple as marker locations can be updated.  For color I need to access a particular path on the image, which is an svg. Rotation should also be able to be handled if I can access the svg in js.

My thoughts on doing this were to load the svg in js, then modify this as needed before I assign it to a custom icon. Is there a simple way to load an svg in js so that it can be thusly manipulated without it being part of the DOM?

Any advice appreciated

Comment: What's the problem with the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate an SVG with DOM methods but not include it in your main DOM, you'll want to use [createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).